# a project A rely on shared library B, B rely on C, A don't rely on C, why I need to find_package and targe_link C in CMakelist.txt of A?

Tags: cmake

a project A rely on shared library B, B relies on third-party library C, A doesn't rely on C, why do I need to find_package C in CMakelist.txt of A? The third-party library C is PCL.

**The CMakelist.txt of shared library B.**

```
add_library(TdLib SHARED
        pcl_tools.cpp
        pcl_tools.h
        )

#PCL
find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(HEADER_FILES
        pcl_tools.h
        )
set_target_properties(TdLib PROPERTIES
        PUBLIC_HEADER
        "${HEADER_FILES}"
        )

target_link_libraries(TdLib
                    ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
                    )

install(TARGETS TdLib
        # IMPORTANT: Add the foo library to the "export-set"
        EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}" COMPONENT bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}/TdLibrary"
        COMPONENT dev)
```

I install B by

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:=/home/wang/CLionProjects/TdLibrary/install
make
make install
```

**The CMakelist.txt of project A.**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#TdLib
set(TdLib_DIR "/home/wang/CLionProjects/TdLibrary/install/lib/CMake/TdLib/")
find_package(TdLib REQUIRED)
include_directories(${TdLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})
MESSAGE(STATUS "TdLib_INCLUDE_DIRS = " ${TdLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#PCL
find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(openMpTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(openMpTest
        ${TdLib_LIBRARIES}
        )
```

If I comment the code`find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)`,
error will occur like below:

```
Scanning dependencies of target openMpTest
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Test
/usr/bin/ld: Cannot find -lvtkChartsCore
/usr/bin/ld: Cannot find -lvtkCommonColor
/usr/bin/ld: Cannot find -lvtkCommonDataModel
...
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make:117: recipe for target 'Test' failed
make[2]: *** [Test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: not sure about the version, but with newer version you should be using `target_link_libraries(TdLib PRIVATE ${PCL_LIBRARIES})` to make sure not to transitively inherit the dependencies

Comment: Yes, you are right. After I add the PRIVATE option, the problem is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification on the CMakelist.txt of B:

```
target_link_libraries(TdLib PRIVATE
                    ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
                    )
```

PRIVATE option means the dependencies is used only by the B. A that relies on B doesn't need to find_package(C).