# Project A rely on shared library B, B rely on C, A don't rely on C. When I use an API of B, warning B can't find C

Tags: c++, cmake

A project `A` relies on shared library `B`, `B` relies on `C`, `A` doesn't rely on `C`. `B` is compiled and installed as a shared library. When `A` uses an API of `B`, a warning occurs that `B` can't find `C` as the code shows.

In that code `A` is `LibTest`. `B` is `TdLib`. `C` is `pangolin`.

```
Scanning dependencies of target LibTest
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LibTest.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable LibTest
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpangolin.so, needed by /home/wang/CLionProjects/TdLibrary/install/lib/libTdLib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/wang/CLionProjects/TdLibrary/install/lib/libTdLib.so: 'pangolin::CreateDisplay()’ undefined reference
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/LibTest.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target 'LibTest' failed
make[3]: *** [LibTest] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:109: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/LibTest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/LibTest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:121: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/LibTest.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/LibTest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:131: recipe for target 'LibTest' failed
make: *** [LibTest] Error 2
```

The `CMakelist.txt` of shared library `B`.

```
add_library(TdLib SHARED
        pangolin_tools.cpp
        pangolin_tools.h
        )

#pangolin
find_package(Pangolin REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Pangolin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

set(HEADER_FILES
        pangolin_tools.h
        )
set_target_properties(TdLib PROPERTIES
        PUBLIC_HEADER
        "${HEADER_FILES}"
        )

target_link_libraries(TdLib PRIVATE
                    ${Pangolin_LIBRARIES}
                    )

install(TARGETS TdLib
        # IMPORTANT: Add the foo library to the "export-set"
        EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}" COMPONENT bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}/TdLibrary"
        COMPONENT dev)
```

I install `B` by

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:=/home/wang/CLionProjects/TdLibrary/install
make
make install
```

The `CMakelist.txt` of project `A`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(LibTest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#TdLib
set(TdLib_DIR "/home/wang/CLionProjects/TdLibrary/install/lib/CMake/TdLib/")
find_package(TdLib REQUIRED)
include_directories(${TdLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(LibTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(LibTest ${TdLib_LIBRARIES}
```

Comment: If A depends on B, and B depends on C, A depends on C indirectly. A may not be able to use B if C is not available. CMake is able to detect indirect dependencies. This is how I read _`libpangolin.so, needed by /home/wang/CLionProjects/TdLibrary/install/lib/libTdLib.so`_

Comment: Have you tried target_link_Libraries(Tdlib PUBLIC $(pangolin_LIBRARIES) ? (instead of private)

Comment: @Gojita I add the PRIVATE because of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660547/a-project-a-rely-on-shared-library-b-b-rely-on-c-a-dont-rely-on-c-why-i-need) I posted in the past few days.

Comment: @Scheff But from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660547/a-project-a-rely-on-shared-library-b-b-rely-on-c-a-dont-rely-on-c-why-i-need) that I posted in the past few days ago, the CMake support this kind of indirect dependencies.

Comment: @tingda zhuang: But you still need to add the path where to find library C when you link A. For me, if A depends on B that depends on C ... A depends on C except if C is link statically inside B. Otherwise, when linking A with B, you will need information about where to find library C

Comment: @Gojita but as you can see from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660547/a-project-a-rely-on-shared-library-b-b-rely-on-c-a-dont-rely-on-c-why-i-need), when C is PCL, project A works well.

Answer (score 0):

You're most certainly linking against shared libraries.

In the following, I would remove the `PRIVATE` keyword:

```
target_link_libraries(TdLib PRIVATE
                    ${Pangolin_LIBRARIES}
                    )
```

and see whether that helps. On my end, I've noticed that you can link libraries without any `target_link_libraries()` which then force you to add the libraries at the time you build the executable.

I guess also that this `PRIVATE` keyword may not do exactly what you think.

Comment: A `PRIVATE` keyword has been added because of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660547/a-project-a-rely-on-shared-library-b-b-rely-on-c-a-dont-rely-on-c-why-i-need) from the same author.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke, As the Tsyvarev said, I add the PRIVATE to avoid add C in A's CMakelists.txt when I use B that relies on C.